# Create Publishing Web Exception: "PublishingPageStatusIndicator.AppendTranslationStatus"

Tags: 2013, error, publishing-site

When creating a Publishing child/sub-Web (but not a grandchild/sub-sub-web), we get the following strange error.

```
    Line 125201: 07/03/2014 12:07:55.56     w3wp.exe (0x253C)                           0x1140  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingPageStatusIndicator.AppendTranslationStatus(StringBuilder sb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingPageStatusIndicator.RenderStatusString(Page page, String cssClass, String id, String& customStatusKey)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageStateControl.PopulateStatusMessages()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPPageStateControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageStateControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     a... 72c2a09c-4754-10c2-8f75-7b8148bab3a2
    Line 125202: 07/03/2014 12:07:55.56*    w3wp.exe (0x253C)                           0x1140  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...t System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 72c2a09c-4754-10c2-8f75-7b8148bab3a2
    Line 125203: 07/03/2014 12:07:55.56     w3wp.exe (0x253C)                           0x1140  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingPageStatusIndicator.AppendTranslationStatus(StringBuilder sb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingPageStatusIndicator.RenderStatusString(Page page, String cssClass, String id, String& customStatusKey)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageStateControl.PopulateStatusMessages()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPPageStateControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageSta... 72c2a09c-4754-10c2-8f75-7b8148bab3a2
    Line 125204: 07/03/2014 12:07:55.56*    w3wp.exe (0x253C)                           0x1140  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...teControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplicatio...  72c2a09c-4754-10c2-8f75-7b8148bab3a2
    Line 125205: 07/03/2014 12:07:55.56*    w3wp.exe (0x253C)                           0x1140  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...n.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   72c2a09c-4754-10c2-8f75-7b8148bab3a2
```

Interestingly, the Web is created and the user able to continue to the web after getting the error page. We also see another strange error (multiple times) in the logs with same correlation token:

```
Line 123876: 07/03/2014 12:07:50.27     w3wp.exe (0x253C)                           0x1140  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer...
```

There's also some mention of caching, but doesn't appear to be directly related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you customize your Master Page? if yes then change master page to default then try again.

check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/f1887795-f2d6-4653-8cb4-a0ebd95f89fa/enable-disable-publishingpagestatusindicator-on-a-sharepoint2010-document-library

What error you are getting in the browser? You may try to deactivate and re activate the publishing infrastructure features.